# Restoring Windows 8.1 is blocked by UEFI

Tags: windows-8, usb-flash-drive, uefi, system-restore

I accidentally wiped my Windows partitions while installing Ubuntu, but fortunately, I did a complete backup before trying to install it. The laptop is a Yoga 2 Pro, if that helps at all.

The Windows 8.1 install media I'm using is a USB stick. When I try to boot from it in UEFI mode, the USB drive is not detected. When I run it in Legacy (BIOS) mode, the System Restore tool says that I can't install the image because they were generated under UEFI mode. How do I deal with this?

Comment: You have disabled `Secure Boot` to eliminate any conflicts with it correct?  The USB itself has EFI drivers correct?

Comment: @Ramhound Honestly, I didn't know that it had to have EFI drivers. I'll check to see if Secure Boot is disabled.

Comment: @Ramhound secure boot is disabled. How would I go about knowing whether I have EFI drivers?

Comment: how did you created the USB sick? The USB stick also needs GPT layout to work in UEFI mode and must be FAT32, not NTFS.

Comment: You just look a the drive.  It should have an EFI folder.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to access it using [Rufus](http://rufus.akeo.ie/) to create a UEFI-compatible disk, as was suggested by the other members.